# Translations of Deuring

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, elliptic-curves

As the title suggests, do there exist translations of papers by Deuring?
I'm particularly interested in:

- "Die Typen der Multiplikatorenringe elliptischer Funktionenkörper," *Ach. Math. Sem. Hab.* (1941), pp. 197-272.
- "Die Klassenkörper der Komplexen Multiplikation," *Enzyklopädie der Math. Wiss.* Band I, 2. Teil, Heft 10, Teil II.

Thanks for the help in advance!

EDIT: Perhaps someone could suggest books/notes to read so that I can get a grip on the concepts in the paper.

I see Deuring mentioning "Elliptische Funktionenkörper" (is this the function field of the elliptic curve or the modular function field?) and he also mentions actions on this field. Is there a modern treatment of this that I can refer to?

Comment: Max Deuring wrote 26 publications, one in Italian, the rest in German, no translations listed in his bibliography.

Comment: Have you tried the improved Google Translate?  I've used it recently  also on a German paper.  it forced me to think harder about the various statements and make-up a few gaps  generated by the translation. Ironicaly, this made me a more involved reader.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu I know some rudimentary german and have also tried to use Google translate but I am still unable to understand the paper well.

Answer (score 4):

An English translation of "[Die Klassenkörper der Komplexen Multiplikation](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=167481)" was posted on arXiv by [CheeWhye Chin](https://www.genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=69510) in 2020: https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.04531

English translation of the proofs of many theorems from "[Die Typen der Multiplikatorenringe elliptischer Funktionenkörper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02940746)" can be found in

- chapter 14 (eg. Theorem 14.18) of Cox's Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$ (2nd edition, 2013),
- chapter 13 of Lang's [Elliptic Functions](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-4752-4) (2nd edition, 1987), and
- chapter II (section 4 and 5) of Silverman's [Advanced Topics in the Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-0851-8) (1st edition, 1994).
- Historical discussion about this paper is available in section 8.4 of Roquette's [The Riemann Hypothesis in Characteristic p in Historical Perspective](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-99067-5) (1st edition, 2018)